# Java boolean returning null after having been defined

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

After looking through multiple other questions similar, I still seem to have this problem. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12992025/what-is-the-correct-way-to-declare-a-boolean-variable-in-java) seems to be the only relavent post, but it still does not answer my question. The issue I'm having is in my main function I establish a boolean, but in a function I call after that it gives me an NPE. Shown here:

```
public class Display extends JFrame {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public JPanel gp = (JPanel) getGlassPane();
public Images i;
public ActualGameClass p;
public Draw d;
public Controls c;
public boolean AllLoaded = false;

public Display(){
    i = new Images();
    gp.setVisible(true);
    c = new Controls(this, d);
    c.loadControls();
    p = new ActualGameClass();
    d = new Draw(p, i);
    i.loadImages();
    System.out.println(c.ControlsLoaded);
    AllLoaded = true;
    gp.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1, 0, 0));
    this.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1, 0, 0));

    gp.add(d, p);
    this.add(i);
    p.Game();
}
```

then in the class ActualGameClass.java

```
public void Game(){
    if(Main.f.AllLoaded){
    //game
    }
}
```

When I run this code, it points me to the

```
if(Main.f.AllLoaded)
```

saying there is an NPE.

Because it was requested and I'm having trouble formatting in the comments:
Main is just what I use to set a window in JFrame here's the relevant class

```
public class Main {

public static Display f = new Display();
public static int w =
        Main.f.ResChoiceW + 0;
public static int h = 
        Main.f.ResChoiceH +22; //Top Bar of GP renders as 22px
public static void main(String args[]){
    f.setSize(w, h);
    f.setResizable(false);
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setTitle("Eddy's Adventures");
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setAlwaysOnTop(false);
}
```

and the Stacktrace

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.fireFlower.pasterino.ActualGameClass.Game(ActualGameClass.java:24)
        at com.fireFlower.pasterino.Display.<init>(Display.java:31)
        at com.fireFlower.pasterino.Main.<clinit>(Main.java:7)
```

Comment: What is `.f` and where is `Main`? Also, show the stacktrace.

Comment: Please post the whole class if it's not too big. This is not enough information to answer your question.

Comment: @user3386026 a `boolean` can;t be `null`, but `Main.f` might be.

Comment: You could narrow it down to whether Main is null or f is null. If you can't use the IDE to tell, before the line that gives you problems insert System.out.println("Main == null is " + (Main==null)); System.out.println("f == null is " + (Main.f==null));

Comment: @aliteralmind
I added the whole class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're running `p.Game();` *inside* of the `Display` constructor and that references a variable that is also assigned inside the constructor of `Display`, you will be referencing an incompletely constructed `Display` object.

This should help with understanding: http://vlkan.com/blog/post/2014/02/14/java-safe-publication/

Comment: how do you suggest I fix this issue, since I want 'p.Game()' to run but anytime I try to call it with a function out of Display it is not yet constructed.

Comment: Can you elaborate how the `Display` object is incomplete? Since `p.Game()` is the last line of code in the constructor, I don't understand how it would be a problem. It's not a *good idea* to recursively call back to itself (Display-->Game-->Display), but I don't understand how it's breaking things. Not doubting your answer, just not understanding it.

Comment: @aliteralmind Just have a look at the link. It revolves around multi-thread access to shared objects and they do a better job of explaining it than I can.

Comment: @user3386026 A better design is to remove the boolean entirely and add a delegator method which you call explicitly to start the game.

Answer (score 0):

To continue from @JustinJasmann`s answer:

1. Eliminate the call to `p.Game()` in your `Display` constructor. Recursive calls should be avoided unless you really know what you're doing.
2. Eliminate the `AllLoaded` variable entirely
3. Change `void Game()` to `void Game(Display disp)`
4. As the last line in your main (I think), call `Game(f)`.

And consider naming your variables to be more indicative of what they are, and to follow naming conventions:

```
f         --> disp
void Game --> void startGame   //Functions should start with lowercase.
w         --> resNum  ??
h         --> resNumH
```

and so on.